# suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of '|' [-Werror=parentheses] ESP8266 spi

Tags: c, esp8266

The VScode complains about the last **&dout_data)**

```
WRITE_PERI_REG(SPI_W0(spi_no),((0xFFFFFFFF<<(dout_bits-dout_extra_bits)&dout_data)<<(8-dout_extra_bits)|
                                            (0xFFFFFFFF>>(32-(dout_bits-dout_extra_bits)))&dout_data));
                                                                                          ^
```

and **command&**

```
WRITE_PERI_REG (SPI_USER2 (spi_no),((((cmd_bits-1)&SPI_USR_COMMAND_BITLEN)<<SPI_USR_COMMAND_BITLEN_S)|
                                            command&SPI_USR_COMMAND_VALUE));
                                            ^
```

Strange to see as these warnings i didnt see when i was compiling with older version SDK

Comment: I fail to see a question here..?

Comment: How did that line with all those operations crammed into one unreadable blob ever pass code review?!?!  I'm not going to spend 10 minutes trying to pull it apart and figure out what it actually does.

Comment: @AKX the question is how to fix it

Comment: @AndrewHenle thats not my code. https://github.com/somhi/ESP8266/blob/master/SDK%20samples/basicApp%2BSPI_0.2/user/spi.c

Comment: the warning is clear, put parentheses around that to prevent confusion

Comment: File a bug report/issue then - and reference this question.  Someone wants to write an unmaintainable mess that generates warnings and then publish it?  Let 'em fix it themselves.  Maybe they'll learn.

Comment: @phuclv *put parentheses around that to prevent confusion*  Yeah, that'll make that mess readable...  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The VScode complains about the last &dout_data) … and command&

The compiler message “suggest parentheses around arithmetic in operand of '|'” means the compiler is suggesting you put parentheses around the subexpression it is pointing to with the `^`. That would be around `(0xFFFFFFFF>>(32-(dout_bits-dout_extra_bits)))&dout_data` in the first case and around `command&SPI_USR_COMMAND_VALUE` in the second case.

> Strange to see as these warnings i didnt see when i was compiling with older version SDK

New software often brings new features, including new warnings or new detections of things to warn about.

Answer (score 0):

This overagressive warning is present in many compilers -- it would seem that tool vendors believe that most people don't know that and (`&`) has higher precedence than or (`|`) so warn you if you use expressions that most people would find perfectly clear like

```
a & b | c & d
```

and want you to add the extra redundant parentheses for clarity

```
(a & b) | (c & d)
```

oddly, they rarely warn about `+` and `*` which are equally common.

Comment: the precedence of `+` and `*` is clear. It's silly to do things like `(a*b) + (c*d)` which does harm and reduces readability

Comment: @phuclv The precedence of `&` and `|` is equally clear, and it is equally silly to do things like `(a&b) | (c&d)` which does equal harm and also reduces readability.  But the warning suggests it.

Comment: not at all, `+` and `*` are well-known since everyone learned that in math, but bitwise operators are completely unused out of programming so not everyone learned it by heart so a warning is highly necessary